# public iCloud Data

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

for my new app, I need to save data generated by the user (e.g. gps positions). First I thought I save these data within the icloud storage.

Problem is, I would like to add the possibility to share a few data with friends. Therefore these data needs to be public.

Is this possible within icloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/) for that:

> With CloudKit, you can focus on your client-side app development and
>   let iCloud eliminate the need to write server-side application logic.
>   CloudKit provides you with Authentication, private and public
>   database, structured and asset storage services

Comment: I wasn't aware that there's a public space.